# How to access encryption endpoint for Pivotal Spring Cloud Service config server

Tags: spring-cloud, pivotal-web-services, cloud-foundry

I am using Pivotal Cloud Foundry with Spring Cloud Services 1.0.0. I am wondering what the proper way to access the /encryption endpoint is on our Config Server service instance? I get an OAuth "Full authentication required" error when trying to access the endpoint but I am not sure with what credentials I should authenticate with I don't even know if the encryption endpoint is setup, there is nothing in the documentation to suggest it is or isn't available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You either need to look at the logs during startup to capture the generated password OR you need to provide a password in your startup configs.

Add this to your bootstrap.yml

```
security:
  user:
    password: yourPasswordHere
```

Or add this to your bootstrap.properties:

```
security.user.password: yourPasswordHere
```

You can login with user/yourPasswordHere to authenticate once your application has been deployed.